# Variable within constructor is returning null?

Tags: java

I am doing a project based around the concepts of inheritance and have created a super constructor which has two variables within itself (String, int), this super constructor is then called within a sub constructor that inherited the super constructors class. I then use two methods to return the properties of those variables within the constructors. The age property is outputting fine but the String property is returning null. Here's the code:

**Animal super-class**

```
abstract public class Animal 
{

    int age;
    String name;

Animal(String name, int age)   
{
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
} 


Animal()
{
  this("newborn", 0);
}


public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

}
```

**Wolf sub-class**

```
public class Wolf extends Carnivore
{

    String name;
    int age;

Wolf(String name, int age)   
{  
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Wolf()
{
  super();
}

    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }  

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

}
```

**Main method class**

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    Wolf newWolf = new Wolf();
    System.out.println("Name = " + newWolf.getName());
    System.out.println("Age = " + newWolf.getAge());

}
}
```

Age is returning as 0 which is correct but `System.out.println("Name = " + newWolf.getName());` seems to be returning null instead of "newborn". Any help on resolving this issue is appreciated thanks.

**Update** - I need the `getName()` method for another constructor that I haven't included in this example so is there a way to have them both exist?

Comment: Remove the `getName()` method from `Wolf`. That returns the value of `Wolf.name`, which you never set. Remove `Wolf.name` too. (Same goes for `getAge()` and `age` in `Wolf`).

Comment: You're tricked, `age` is not returning the 0 you think it is returning. It's returning the default `int` value, which happens to be 0. It isn't the one you specified in the constructor of `Animal`.

Comment: The issue is, I have another constructor that requires the getName() method.

Comment: Just remove it, it'll be inherited from the parent class.

Comment: Don't duplicate the fields.  That way, madness lies.  A `Wolf` doesn't need its own `name` and `age` outside of the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are defining your fields in the sub-class, you don't need to as they are inherited from the parent.

Your class has two sets of fields, one from the super (these are the ones set by your constructor, which is calling `super()` and the other from the child class (these are the ones returned by your getters, which are not initialized. the zero is int's default, not set either).

So simply remove the fields definition from the child class